# Issue editing multi forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery example using pop ups:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

  <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
  <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

When I do click on EDIT it should obtain the information and edit the row but is not working.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUXP5/15/)

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Some jquery code too, perhaps?

Comment: Working: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/nUXP5/16/

Comment: Is working but not getting the information of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/YTzU2/)**

Here is the code js:

```
$(function() {
    var dialog, form,

      name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addUser() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      //valid = valid && checkRegexp( email,/^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i,  "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }



    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

      //create user dialog 
      /*dialogs = $( "#dialog-forms" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": addUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });*/

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addUser();
    });



    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });

    //edit user dailog 
    edit_dialogs = $( "#edit-dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Edit user details": editUser,
        Cancel: function() {
          edit_dialogs.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    edit_form = edit_dialogs.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      editUser();
    });

    var current_edit_row_details={};

     function editUser() {
      var valid = true;
      //console.log('current_edit_row_details = ');
      //console.log(current_edit_row_details);

      var tds = $(current_edit_row_details.current_row).children('td');

      var name = $('#edit_name').val();//current_edit_row_details.name;
      var email = $('#edit_email').val();//current_edit_row_details.email;
      var password = $('#edit_password').val(); //current_edit_row_details.password;

        tds[0].innerHTML = name;           
        tds[1].innerHTML = email;    
        tds[2].innerHTML = password;   
        edit_dialogs.dialog( "close" );

      //allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      /*valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      //valid = valid && checkRegexp( email,/^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i,  "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );

      }*/
      return valid;
    }

    $( ".edit-user" ).click(function() {

       var tds = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
       //alert(tds[0].innerHTML) 
       var name = tds[0].innerHTML;
       var email = tds[1].innerHTML; 
       var password = tds[2].innerHTML; 

       $('#edit_name').val(name);
       $('#edit_email').val(email);
       $('#edit_password').val(password);

       current_edit_row_details.name = name;
       current_edit_row_details.email = email;
       current_edit_row_details.password = password;
       current_edit_row_details.current_row = $(this).closest('tr'); 

       edit_dialogs.dialog( "open" );
       //console.log(tds); 
    });     
  });
```